# Eclipse PDT .sql always Save As

Tags: sql, eclipse, save-as

I have a number of .sql files in my work space, one of them, when I save it always brings up the Save As dialogue, even though it is already saved. The other peculiarness is that there are 3 other files in the same folder that don't have this behaviour, instead they open the systems default editor (GEdit).

When I save the file in question I also get an error message: "Save Failed
org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.editor.RefactorableFileEditorInp ut cannot be cast to org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.editor.input.NonExistingPHPFileE ditorInput "

Can anyone advise where to look for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error: Open with "internal editor" -> text editor solves the problem

Comment: I have the same problem. Yes - this solves the saving problem, but I no get none of the syntax highlighting or any other PHP-specific features.